# UITableView cell accessory color in iOS 13

Tags: ios, uitableview

Prior to iOS 13, it was possible to change the tableView cells accessory (disclosure indicator for example) color by setting the tableView tint color.
This no longer works and accessory always remains gray regardless of the tint color.

Is this a bug or a new behavior?
Is there a way to change the cell accessory color?

Comment: This was always a dubious use of the tint color. If you want an accessory whose color you are in charge of, use an accessory _view_ instead of a built-in accessory type.

Comment: that works, Thanks!